# django postgresql - extra datetime

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In my project I have object with datetime field

```
startdate = models.DateTimeField(default="1999-01-01 00:00:00")
```

I need create new object and send datetime = "2015-12-9"

```
calen = models.calendar()
calen.startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")
calen.save()
```

In this object I see

```
    calen.startdate => datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 0, 0)
```

all right.

in pqAdmin3, postgres DB this field = "2015-12-09 08:00:00+02"

wrong 8 hours!!!! ->6+2

When I select this object calen.startdate

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

extra 6:00!!!!

I tried to make a complete date, now(),but all the same is extra 6 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `django.utils.datetime` for database fields. Use `timezone` instead.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you. It is work only timezone.now(), but how I can get data from my string "datetime.strptime" and convert to timezone object

Comment: You can use `timezone.strptime`. This module is compatible with `datetime`, but also has time zones support.

Comment: Sorry, right, it doesn't. If so - you can use `datetime`, but make sure you have `tzinfo` parameter in your datetime object. You may use `timezone.localtime(value)` to convert `datetime` object to `datetime-with-timezone` object